# spring boot : eureka discovery client error LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

here's the full error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class \[org.springframework.cloud.loadbalancer.config.LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration\] from ClassLoader \[jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4b1210ee\]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) \~\[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) \~\[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) \~\[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:669) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:661) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1302) \~\[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:864) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:852) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:839) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:779) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11\]
at org.sid.BillingServiceApplication.main(BillingServiceApplication.java:10) \~\[classes/:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) \~\[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.11.jar:2.7.11\]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/aot/BeanRegistrationAotProcessor
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3434) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2536) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) \~\[spring-core-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27\]
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.BeanRegistrationAotProcessor
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) \~\[na:na\]
... 37 common frames omitted
```

here's the pom.xml file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
here's the main code : 
package org.sid;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class BillingServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BillingServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

here's the application.proprities

```
\</project\>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was a problem with the pom.xml file here's the correct version :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.8</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).